# Pull Specific Data from a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

It pulled out information in an array.  I'm looking to pull the VIN from the data below;

Used 2019 Kia Rio LX Available APR 3.9%  for 75 months .  Payments wi
th approved credit, 20 percent down plus tax title and fees. Zero down
options available upon request! (with approval) Finance payment of $1
80/mo. is based on Buy for of $14,988 with $2,997 down at 3.99% APR fi
nancing for 72 months.  Payments with approved credit, 20 percent down
plus tax title and fees. Zero down options available upon request! (w
ith approval) Buy for $14,988. Stock#: D71741S. **Vin: 3KPA24AB6KE184683**
. Model code: 31422. *Photos are for illustration purposes only. Sale
ends 08-31-2020'

I just need help with a javascript variable or anything that would just pull out the VINS.

Comment: This seems like two completely separate questions. What does the function have to do with getting the vin number out of the paragraph?

Comment: I was just showing how I pulled the paragraph off the website.  And then asking how I pull the VIN from the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

You can use this RegEx (from [Here](https://rgxdb.com/r/61PVCR9B)):

```
(?<wmi>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d]{3})(?<vds>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d]{5})(?<check>[\dX])(?<vis>(?<year>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d])(?<plant>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d])(?<seq>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d]{6}))
```

Example:

```js
var string = `Used 2019 Kia Rio LX Available APR 3.9% for 75 months . Payments wi th approved credit, 20 percent down plus tax title and fees. Zero down options available upon request! (with approval) Finance payment of $1 80/mo. is based on Buy for of $14,988 with $2,997 down at 3.99% APR fi nancing for 72 months. Payments with approved credit, 20 percent down plus tax title and fees. Zero down options available upon request! (w ith approval) Buy for $14,988. Stock#: D71741S. Vin: 3KPA24AB6KE184683 . Model code: 31422. *Photos are for illustration purposes only. Sale ends 08-31-2020'`;

var matches = string.match(/(?<wmi>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d]{3})(?<vds>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d]{5})(?<check>[\dX])(?<vis>(?<year>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d])(?<plant>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d])(?<seq>[A-HJ-NPR-Z\d]{6}))/g);

var vin = matches[0];

console.log(vin);
```